# Capturing Receipt Data from receipt printer after transaction c#

Tags: c#, printing, serial-port, receipt, pos

I am working on a device which will be sitting in between the POS and receipt printer, what does the device will do is it will capture the raw receipt data that is being sent to the printer and save it locally, as a text file or JSON.

I am new to working with a POS system and basically I am trying to figure out how to collect receipt data before or while it is being printed and transmit that data to a third party device.

Any guide would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you find your answer? I'm in the same process: I want to know how I can capture such data. In my case I want to capture it through an Arduino unit. Any ideas so far?

Comment: @SebastianPlasschaert, not completely. If you don't mind can I ask you what is the device that you working on? Are you also looking for a universal approach?

Comment: Yes, I am. But in my case I don’t want to store it just locally, but I first want to show the data as a QR-code on a small display (Arduino) and then I also will send it to an SaaS (Rails API).

Comment: Aha. So, if anyone here can help us or give some hint that would be great.

Comment: Did anyone find answer? I'm in the same process: I want to know how I can capture such data.